# sharepoint 2013 list - Column items with number grouped go from 1, 2, 3...9, 10, 12,

Tags: list, grouping

I have a SharePoint list where I have placed a number before a column item so users will understand the proper steps to take. I did this so when I group the items, the group would list the items from steps 1-15. The issue is once I get to 10, 12, 13, and so on, SharePoint places those items with two digits (10, 11, 12, 13, etc.) before the items that have the number 2. I thought about creating an Order column, but I need to be able to group by the column with the step, grouping by the order column would be meaningless for biz partners.

Answer (score 3):

This is how string based sorting works. To make it function numerically, either change your column to a number and sort ascending and it will work, or change your strings to 01, 02, 03, etc and it will sort properly.